# Dataproc Serverless Interactive custom environment variables

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, environment-variables, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a problem with setting up custom environment variables in Dataproc Serverless Interactive PySpark sessions. I follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/properties#supported_spark_properties) and setup up my python environment variable using `spark.dataproc.driverEnv.MY_VAR=my_value`. Once I do it in batch mode, environment variables are accessible without hesitation. However in the interactive mode, they are not. Any ideas what might be wrong or is there any walkaround for interactive sessions?

I set them up using `spark.dataproc.driverEnv.MY_VAR=my_value` config in session template. Then I call them using

```
import os
os.getenv("MY_VAR")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Dataproc Serverless Sessions does not support `spark.dataproc.driverEnv.` properties.

Comment: Is there a way how to use/propagate environment variables into Dataproc Serverless Sessions? Any possible walkaround? Or is the support planned?